# Duplicating Data in Another Table for Performance Gain

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, database-design

I'm currently designing the database architecture for a product that I'm in the process of building. I'm simply drawing out everything in an Excel file before I begin creating everything in MySQL.

Currently, I have two different tables that are almost identical to one another.

`TABLE A` that contains the most recent values of each data point for each user.

`TABLE B` that contains daily records of each data point for each user.

My reasoning for creating `TABLE A`, instead or relying solely on `TABLE B`, is that the number of rows in `TABLE B` will grow everyday by the number of customers I have. For instance, say I have 20,000 customers, `TABLE B` will grow by 20,000 rows every single day. So by creating `TABLE A`, I'll only ever have to search through 20,000 records to find the most recent values of each data point for each user since I'll be updating these values everyday; whereas for `TABLE B`, I'd have to search through an ever-growing number of rows for the most recent insertion for each user.

Is this acceptable or good practice?

Or should I just forget about `TABLE A` to reduce "bloat" in my database?

Comment: You're talking about making a derivative set of data that's optimized around your read requirements. This is normal. The key here is to do it in a way that you can verify that table A is an accurate reflection of what's in B and the two don't fall out of sync. One way to do this is to make table A a `VIEW` and periodically materialize it, or update with triggers.

Comment: @tadman im pretty new to MySQL so im having trouble understanding this `VIEW` thingy, and materializing it, and triggers. i was simply going to update `TABLE A` every time i insert a daily record into `TABLE B`.

Comment: You can automate that update using a trigger, and the `VIEW` part is how you populate the table initially. Those are concepts worth reading up on if you're not entirely familiar so you know what tools you have.

Comment: @tadman i will def read about them today! the thing is all of this is going to be automated anyways. from the scraping, to the uploading, to the handling/processing of data (i.e. the insertion and updates thereof). but i will still read about those other things nonetheless

Comment: @tadman just found out that unfortunately my hosting plan will not allow me to use partitions on shared hosting :( wish i had checked that before spending so much time reading about it lol

Comment: Shared hosting is an anachronism these days because with even a very modest budget you can use managed database services like [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) to give you a full-featured database install you control. There's many other "cloud hosted" solutions at differing price points that might serve you better than the default, usually pretty shoddy shared database hosting these providers often have.

Comment: If this is not "business critical", your own desktop/laptop will do fine for quite some time.  Even at 20K rows/day, you might not over-fill your machine in a year.

Comment: @RickJames oh im not worried about the storage size of the database, just the performance/execution times. these 2 particular tables should take up less than 200 **mega**bytes after a **year.** notably this will be a "business critical" environment however

Comment: @Anthony - Performance usually boils down to (*) Indexes (especially 'composite', see [_my blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql), (*) formulation of queries, (*) schema design.  Tuning and "throwing hardware at the problem" are rarely useful.

Comment: @RickJames thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right approach.  You basically have two reasonable options:

1. Use indexes on the history table to access the most recent day's records.
2. Use table partitioning to store each day in a separate partition.

You *can* manage two tables, but that is a lot of trouble and there are built-in methods to handle this situation.

Comment: wouldn't i have to update the index every time i insert new daily records into `TABLE B` though? im pretty new to MySQL so i really dont understand partitioning. does this mean that, even tho all the daily records would be stored in `TABLE B`, `TABLE B` can/would be partitioned into "separate" tables based on, say, the values of a date column??

Comment: @Anthony . . . The index is updated automatically.  My guess is that for 30,000 records/day, you won't notice the increase in time.  It will take longer than inserting without the index, but not a whole lot longer.

Comment: oh, im not worried about inserting the data. my concern is about selecting data. u sure the index would be automatically updated? new records will be continually inserted into `table b` on a daily basis, and the most recent records are the ones ill need access to/have to `select`. is my assumption about how partitions work roughly on point or am i misunderstanding it?

Comment: @Anthony . . . Partitions and indexes are different things.  However, both are efficient if you have `where date = ?` in the `where` clause.

Comment: yeah i know they are different things. ok i get what youre saying now. anyways, i just found out that unfortunately my hosting plan will not allow me to use partitions on shared hosting :( wish i had checked that before spending so much time reading about it lol. an index on records from the most recent day should be sufficient to make the execution time reasonable right?

Comment: @anthony . . . I think so.  I would recommend a clustered index because the most recent data is so important.

Comment: ok, sweet. thanks. what's the diff between a clustered index and a plain old index?

Comment: @Anthony . . . A clustered index guarantees that rows with similar key values are adjacent.  This reduces the number of data pages that need to be read when accessing data from a single day.

Comment: Except for rare cases, Partitioning does _not_ speed up `SELECTs` any more than a good index.

Comment: @RickJames so ive read, but the partitioning will come in handy for one of my situations. instead of separating the hashtags into alphabetical tables (i.e. table_[a-z]), i can stick it all in one partitioned table to reduce the number of queries and complexity thereof. at least to my knowledge. ive never used partitions before and just started reading about them the other day

Comment: @Anthony - For a simple search by a key (the hashtag), it's a wash.  Without partitioning, it's a simple drill-down in the BTree (see Wikipedia) to get to the row(s).  With partitioning, first you pick which partition, then drill-down the BTree in that partition.  The tradeoff between picking the partition and having a slightly shallower BTree is a toss up.  While you are reading, add [_my partition blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) to your list.

Comment: @RickJames i really have no reason to partition `TABLE_A`. however, since 'TABLE B' will be getting significantly bigger accumulatively, and since it can be partitioned nicely by years, first letter, both, or something like that, i will be partitioning this table once i switch hosts (because my current host doesnt allow partitioning on shared servers). oh yeah i actually read most of that the other day when i came across one of your other posts in another thread

Answer (score 0):

In situations where I need both "current" data and a "history", that is what I do -- One table with the current data and one with history.  They are possibly indexed differently for the different usage, etc.

I would think through what is different between "history" and "current", then make the tables *different not identical*.

When a new record comes in (or 20K rows in your case), I will at least put it into `Current`.  I may also write it to `History`, thereby keeping it complete (at the cost of a small redundancy).  Or I may move the row(s) to `History` when the next row(s) come into `Current`.

I see no need for `PARTITIONing` unless I intend to purge 'old' data.  In that case, I would use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` and choose weekly/monthly/whatever such that the number of partitions does not exceed about 50.  (If you pick 'daily', `History` will slow down after a few months, just because of the partitioning.)

The 20K rows each day -- Are many of them unchanged since yesterday?  That is probably not the proper way to do things.  Please elaborate on what happens each day.  You should avoid having duplicate rows in `History` (except for the date).

Comment: the 20k rows will usually all be almost if not completely unique. what im doing is scraping data points pertaining to instagram hashtags. corresponding records in both table A and table B will also be unique from one another. one of the tables will hold a minimal amount of data (4 columns total); this is the table that i will be feeding daily roughly 20k daily records. whereas the other table will hold a bunch of derivative metrics derived from the aggregation of those records over time. [cont.]

Comment: ive decided to hold 2 days worth of metrics (instead of just the most current one) in the 'derivative metrics' table (15 columns) and purging the oldest of the two records for each unique hashtag when i scrape and insert a new record each day. so partition would be best for this? the 'derivative metrics' table with 15 columns will always have roughly 40k rows. no more. no less. [2 * total number of unique hashtags]

Comment: @Anthony - Sounds like a [_Summary Table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: that's basically the idea. my spider will scrape the data, create an excel file, upload it to the server so that it can be parsed, and then a php script on the server will process the file/data and insert a record for each hashtag on a daily basis. there will be 4 columns: (1) unique_key, (2) hashtag, (3) data, (4) date_inserted. when php script parses the excel file to create the daily records, ill also be selecting all of the necessary previous daily records to run my calculations, from which ill create a "summary" of values in the other table. never heard of a "summary"

Comment: table until now, but that's basically the idea. i figure it's much more efficient to be storing/caching the values of my metrics in a different, much smaller table on a daily basis, than constantly having to retrieve all of the daily records for a particular hashtag and then run calculations on those records every time a user submits a request or whatever

Comment: quick question: can the length of column names effect the number of potential columns allowed in a table? the reason i ask is that one of my "summary" tables may have roughly 146 columns, 99% of which are simply numbers, half of which are will be percentages (i.e. '82' to represent 82% or '3' to represent 3%)???

Comment: @Anthony - Yes, you understand "summary table".  Is there any reason to keep Excel in the loop?  Seems like the work can be done in SQL and/or PHP.  Are the numbers `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, etc, as appropriate?  Percentages could be `TINYINT` (or `FLOAT` for extra precision).  It does not sound like you are about to hit any limits.  See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits .  For column _names_, see 'General limits'.

Comment: the only thing i use excel for is to temporarily store the data that i'm scraping and then use that file to upload to the server to be processed?? do this without excel, what do u mean? in the table with 146 columns, yes, 72 of those columns can be `tinyint` or likely `float` or `decimal`. isn't `decimal` even more precise than `float`, whereby `decimal` allows me to make accurate calculations based on the data and `float` does not? not that ill need to do calculations... the other 72 will likely need no more than `smallint`

Comment: i have another question again. is the main benefit of partitioning the fact that the partitioning is handled automatically by mysql?

Comment: Float vs decimal -- depends on what the data is used for.  Money should be `DECIMAL`.  Something like an 'average' is just fine in `FLOAT`.

Comment: @Anthony - Yes, MySQL will automatically look in multiple partitions as needed.  But that does not mean it is any faster.